# Sidebar and rendering partial, trying to run a todo app on sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails, I have been recommended to using a sidebar so that on most pages it will show what I want. I currently have an application on its own page called Todo List. It simply let you create a task and displays the tasks. It runs on its own page. Now I want to move that app and let it function in my sidebar. I have implemented my sidebar as follow.

```
/views/layouts/application (in body)
<%= yield :sidebar %>

/views/myapp1/index
<% content_for(:sidebar) do %>
 <% render :partial => "layouts/sidebar" %>
<% end %>


/views/layouts/_sidebar
 <% if logged_in? %>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

  <div class="row", id="container_todo_lists">
   <%= render @todo_lists %>
  </div>

  <div class="links" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mynewtodo_list">
   <%= link_to('New Todo List', 'javascript:;', :id => :random) %>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
 </div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰ Todo List</span>
<script>
 function openNav() {document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";}

 function closeNav() {document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";}
</script>

<% end %> 

<!-- Modal  create action -->
  <%= form_for(@todo_list, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="mynewtodo_list" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Todo</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :title %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :title, class: "form-control todo_list_title" %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :description %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control todo_list_content" %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= submit_tag "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mynewtodo_listclose">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<!-- Modal -->
```

I get this error

```
 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.
```

I think I know part of the problem is my

```
@todo_lists
```

Because I tried to called the sidebar on my todo_list page and it works, but the sidebar messed up my original application so that when I press edit and show it would turn the screen grey. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
/views/todo_lists/_todo_list.html.erb
<div class="text-center" id="todo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>">

                <h3 class="panel-title"><%= todo_list.title %>
                  <sup style="color: #3BB2D6; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 15px; text-align:right;">
                      (<%= time_ago_in_words(todo_list.created_at) %>)
                  </sup>
                </h3>

                <p><%= todo_list.description %></p>

                <div class="row" role="group">
                    <div class="links1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myupdatetodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>">
                      <%= link_to('Edit', 'javascript:;', :id => :random) %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="links1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myitemtodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>">
                      <%= link_to('Show', 'javascript:;', :id => :random) %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="links1">
                      <%= link_to 'Destroy', todo_list, method: :delete, remote: true %>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

```
        <!-- Modal - update posts -->
              <%= form_for(todo_list, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
              <div class="modal fade" id="myupdatetodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :title %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :title, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :description %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="myupdatebutton_<%= todo_list.id %>" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <% end %>
        <!-- Modal -->

        <!-- Modal - item posts -->
              <%= form_for(todo_list, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
              <div class="modal fade" id="myitemtodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Items</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">



                  <h3><%= todo_list.title %></h3>
                  <p><%= todo_list.description %></p>



                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="myitembutton_<%= todo_list.id %>" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <%= submit_tag "Add Item", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <% end %>
        <!-- Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, that is because the `@todo_lists` isn't being set, I'm sure if you go back to the previous url that was rendering the view, the sidebar would show.

A way to resolve is to ensure it's set on every page as such:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :set_to_do_lists

  def set_to_do_lists
    @todo_lists ||= TodoList.all #assign this to what's in your todo_lists_path
  end
end
```

With that I guess your app should be fixed

Comment: You can setup all other instance variables required by your sidebar in the method as well. Not sure it's the best way though.

Comment: That bypassed the error, but now I am getting a

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty 

error. It has to do with the todo_list in in the "<% form_for( etc..." shall I declare that as follow?

@todo_list = TodoList.new

is there a guide to setting up instance variables that you have in mind?

Comment: you should do that I think

Comment: That works perfectly! I can see the sidebar. But the ajax is not working for some reason. I used the ajax to make the fill in descriptions and title to pop out but right now it is giving me a gray screen with no pop outs. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think I can guess why it is doing that but I don't know how to fix it. My edit  html code is nested in the "<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">" because it is in my todo_list folder as _todo_list.html.erb and somehow it is not running the code. I only figured it out when I moved my create code as listed above into the nested <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"> and the create link also give me a gray screen

Comment: it's midnight by my time actually 3:20am. If the app is on Github, would help take a look at this when I wake up later in the morning. GH:andela-oakinniranye

Comment: You can upvote/accept the answer since the main issue referenced by the question has been solved

Comment: Thank you so much!